# Pull array values associated with bitmask

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bitmask

I have a simple bitmask, `3` (`"011"` in base 2) which denotes that I should extract `array[0]` and `array[1]` but not `array[2]`

What is an efficient way to do this?

Ultimately, I'm generating a new array with values that passed a `.filter`

Something like this:

```
var bitmask = 37, // "100101"
    array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

var array2 = array.filter((value, index) => {
    // do something with bitmask and index to return true
});

// array2 should be ["a", "c", "f"];
```

Comment: That's not a bitmask, it's a string.

Comment: you're right, but you know what i mean, it's actually a number

Comment: Actually covering it to binary then a string would be usefully, that way you can iterate through it and check for `"1"`.

Comment: the thing is, I'm iterating from 000001 to 111111 so that i can get all possible selections to fill up to 6 slots, not sure i want to loop through a string as well as the array

Comment: Isn't that supposed to return `['a', 'd', 'f']`? Or I get your question wrong.. And what if the bitmask length is higher than the array length?

Comment: @choz opposite because binary counts from the rightmost digit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expanding on your original example you can do this:

```js
var bitmask = 37, // "100101"
    array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

var array2 = array.filter((value, index) => {
    // do something with bitmask and index to return true
    return bitmask & (1 << index);
});

// array2 should be ["a", "c", "f"];
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: sick, thats pretty much perfect, yea I was going to do `(bitmask >> index) % 2` but this is way cleaner

Answer (score 4):

```js
var bitmask = 5, idx=0;
// Loop till bitmask reach 0, works when bitmask >= 0
// If you want to sure instead of implicit type converting (from number to boolean)
// Just change it to while(bitmask >= 0)
while(bitmask){
   // If the rightmost bit is 1, take the array[index]
   if(bitmask & 1) console.log("take arr["+idx+"]");
   // Shift right by 1 bit, say 5 = 101,  this will make the number become 2 = 10
   bitmask>>=1; 
   // Increase the index 
   idx++;
}
```

Using your own example, here is the code works:

```js
var bitmask = 37, // "100101"
    array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
    idx = 0;
var array2 = [];
while(bitmask){
   if(bitmask & 1) array2.push(array[idx]);
   bitmask>>=1; 
   idx++;
}
```

Simply use some bit operation to loop it. As it is looping bit by bit, I think it is the fastest you can get

Comment: @neaumusic add some comments in the code, please see if it is clear enough. As it is simply using the bitmask as a number, no need to convert it to string, no any string operation, and simply loop through all binary bits of bitmask, I think it is the fastest way

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is cast your number into a binary string, then check if the index of the bitmask is `"1"` inside your filter.

```js
    var bitmask = (37).toString(2), // "100101"
        array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
    
    var array2 = array.filter((value, index) => {
        if(bitmask[index] == "1") return value;
    });
    
    console.log(array2);
```

Comment: @neaumusic Just noticed you comment in your question, sorry I assumed it was a typo. You would just need to reverse the string in that case: `var bitmask = (37 >>> 0).toString(2).split("").reverse().join("")`.

Comment: It's all good, these are both correct answers, I'm just trying to determine which is more efficient, and actually I don't think the order matters because I'm getting all permutations either way

Comment: @neaumusic Probably the other answer, it's a basic while loop using bit operators.

Comment: I'm seeing that if `37 >> index` is odd, then it's a match, since the 1's digit exists